# How to find an app is compatible with Intel based Android device or not?

Tags: applications

Intel based Android devices are in the market now and I am drooling over new Asus Zenfone series (which packs Intel Atom processors). However, I am concerned with app compatibility issues.

If an app is developed using SDK, it'll run on Intel based devices, but if it's developed using NDK, it'll surely not run on Intel based devices as instruction sets are different.

Before purchasing any Intel based device, I want to see my favorite apps/games are compatible with it or not. How to get this info without really testing those apps in a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Most application will work fine except the ones which rely on libraries and do not have compatible libs packed in apks.
One quick way to check for a specific app is to open its generic-apk with 7z and check lib folder
Structure of /lib directory inside APK archive is:

```
/lib
    /arm64-v8a
    /armeabi
    /armeabi-v7a
    /mips
    /x86
    /x86_64
```

if it does not have x86 or x86_64 while it has libs in other folders, the chances are that it won't work on intel processors.

You can also use DroidInfo app from playstore to quickly check supported architecture for any installed app on current handset.